Pull packages from private m2 repository with authorization header with ant/ivy
I have spun up a gitea server and uploaded some custom jar which are needed to build the main application.
Custom jars are build from a normal maven setup, which works as it should. But with Ivy/ant I have problems pulling the packages.
But I have troubles setting up the authentication process. From my understanding gitea uses and authorization token to provide access to the packages.
But the ibiblio resolver doesn't support authorization headers. Does anybody have some solutions to get this setup to work?
I want to pull packages from the gitea m2 registery with ivy/ant.
I have tried setting the credentials xml
  <credentials host="gitea.<org>.net"
    realm="Gitea package registery"
    username="read_only"
    passwd="<token>" />

I was also looking at ways to set a custom header. But didn't found any resource on it.
I also tried using the url resolver to no luck.

Using Ivy/Ant ? Why? Why not using Maven..

Old project I want to blow new life in and the ant build is to complicated to convert to maven for the time beign.
But did found the solution.
For future readers use name + api_token generated with that name.
And specify the realm as     realm="Gitea Package API"

Ah that was the question on reddit as well.. Ok..
